# How to define concurrent states in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, statechart

I want to define concurrent states in Ember.js, but the lack of documentation makes it hard to figure out how.

You can define mutually exclusive states (system is either in `foo` or `bar`) like so:

```
App.stateManager = Ember.StateManager.create({
    foo: Ember.State.create({
        //...
    }),
    bar: Ember.State.create({
        //...
    })  
});
```

---

EDIT: Response to [ud3323](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9167659/359104)

Isn't the following concurrent states?

```
App.stateManager = Ember.StateManager.create({
    foo_baz: Ember.State.create({
        foo: Ember.State.create({
           // ...
        }),
        baz: Ember.State.create({
           // ...
        })
    }),
    bar: Ember.State.create({
        //...
    })  
});
```

But how do you define concurrent states such that, for example, when the system is in `foo` state, it is also in `baz` state.

Comment: No those are not concurrent in the way I mean. Concurrent states === orthogonal regions... which would be what you need to have the state machine in 2 or more states at the same time. With the statechart add-on that's easy, just define `substatesAreConcurrent: YES` on any state in which you want its substates to perform like orthogonal regions.

Comment: Ember.StateManager is no longer part of core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For concurrent states you need to use the [statechart add-on](https://github.com/emberjs-addons/sproutcore-statechart). Concurrency is not implemented into enber-states as of yet...

**edit**

Concurrent states === orthogonal regions (in the world of uml state machine design)

Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering, if it can be done as shown in my edited question.

Comment: Is this supported yet? If not, it would be nice if you update your answer when concurrent states are supported.

Comment: No it is not and I'm not sure if it is going to be any time soon.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this Pull request.  It also ties in the routing package as well.
https://github.com/emberjs-addons/sproutcore-statechart/pull/16#issuecomment-3747310

DominikGuzei also created a sample application showing how it is used.  I found it helpful to understand the current (Always chainging) relationship between emberjs and the addons.
https://github.com/DominikGuzei/ember-routing-statechart-example

Answer (score 1):

You can use: [Stativus](http://stativ.us) and get full statechart functionality in emberjs right now. It is a complete re-write of the old SC statecharts without any of the SC cruft.  (gzipped <3k)

Its more full featured and designed to work with any framework.